# Подскажите что бы вы могли посоветывать в плане выбора языка и БД?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, php, mysql

Есть идея сделать проект - чтото вроде социальной сети для фотографов.

Цель попробывать свои силы сделать что то "по глобальней", 
подучить программирование, пару лет пишу на PHP но непрочь и другой язык подучить для саморазвития.

пока мой вгляд остановился на node + mongo

Подскажите что бы вы могли посоветывать в плане выбора языка и БД, 
с условием к примеру страница выростит и начнёт кушать ресурсы?
как никак миллионы фото и тысячи посетителей )))

P.S.: Все "сомнения" начались после просмотра этой [странички](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/)

P.S.2: Не зацыкливайтесь на втором абзаце! Ответьте лучше на вопрос ;)

Comment: myspace - node+extjs насчет того что у них с базой я не знаю

Comment: "подучить программирование"  и вместе с тем "миллионы фото и тысячи посетителей"? Если это не самоирония, то вы большой оптимист

Comment: Оптимист! Но ведь если сидеть на месте и нечего не делать то ....

Comment: про "myspace + node" откуда информация?
разве там не Mura CMS?

Comment: Facebook ведь тоже по началу написали на интузиазме )))

Comment: @stasioman, лучше пишите 1-ую версию, не рассчитанную на миллионы фото и тысячи посетителей, а просто рабочую версию. После написание первой версии у вас будет опыт данной тематики, вы будете более наточены, что позволит вам разработать более хорошую модель.

Comment: > лучше пишите 1-ую версию, не рассчитанную на миллионы фото и тысячи посетителей, а просто рабочую версию

собственно, именно это я и пытался сказать, потому что для начинающего разработчика написание хотя бы небольшого проекта до конца - уже неплохое достижение. А мечты о тысячах и миллионах чаще  приводят к разочарованиям, чем собственно к этим тысячам и миллионам

Comment: >Facebook ведь тоже по началу написали на интузиазме )))

рановато вы себя с Цукербергом сравниваете

Comment: про "фото и посетителей" это конечно же шутка, но любой солдат хотел бы стать. 
Вопрос в другом? 
Что выбрать в этом конкретном случае если язык и дб значения не имеют!

Comment: Что выбрать в этом конкретном случае если язык и дб значения не имеют!

так все-таки если они действительно не имеют значения, то в чем состоит проблема выбора?

Comment: @stasioman, Вам все дали ответ. Созидайте свой продукт используя технологии, которыми Вы владеете на сегодняшний день. Решайте проблемы по мере их поступления.

Comment: @stasioman я ошибся - expressjs фрэймворк, но тоже node http://expressjs.com/applications.html причем похоже уже это основной движек а не new.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите что бы вы могли посоветывать в плане выбора языка и БД

Судя по вашему опыту, посоветую начать писать на том, на чем вы бы хотели писать лет через 5. Если такого языка нету, то пишите на том, что уже хоть как-то знаете.

А вообще, я бы посоветовал php + БД которая поддерживает сервер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 

Я так понимаю, на этом можно закрывать вопрос.

Почемуто никто так и не дочитал до "P.S.2:". 
Извеняюсь за сразу неправельно сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: > Почемуто никто так и не дочитал до "P.S.2:".

потому что он добавлен 1 час назад ) а вопрос я читал 2 часа назад )

Answer (score 3):

> и досихпор не одного ответа по делу!?

Ок, вот вам ответ:

1. Вы судя по всему пишете не коммерческий проект, и делаете это исключительно ради повышения опыта и просто потому что вам интересно этим заниматься (ну и еще, наверное, с  вполне понятной надеждой написать свой супер-сайт с преферансом и барышнями, где можно "грабить корованы" и заниматься прочими богоугодными делами)
2. Вы утверждаете, что "язык и дб значения не имеют!"
3. Вы, надо полагать, сколько-нибудь сносно знаете только PHP

Следовательно, почему бы не писать на том, что знаете, тем более, что язык для этого вполне подходит? Я не знаю, что у вас получится, и получится ли вообще, но это и не важно. Важнее то, что вы сможете получить какой-то полезный опыт, закрепить и расширить имеющиеся знания, тем более, что перед вами нет необходимости "сделать вчера". А вот распыляться на десятки языков и технологий, не изучив на достаточно хорошем уровне хотя бы что-то вряд ли стоит.

И еще, маленькая ремарка - помимо языков программирования не забудьте подтянуть русский язык. Не сочтите за обиду, но то, как вы пишете - просто ужас, и тем самым вы производите впечатление малограмотного и слабообразованного человека, отчего воспринимать вашу деятельность всерьез захотят далеко не все

Comment: Да мне и самому сдыдно за мой Русский! ))) Могу написать на моём "родном" языке, но не думаю что немецкии будет более понятен.


Знания рнр довольно сностные, всего пару лет опыта. Но их вполне хватает для получения честной зарплаты в роле разработчика модулей для e-commerce.

Без обид но снова, и снова ответы про меня а не про вопрос:

"Подскажите что бы вы могли посоветывать в плане выбора языка и БД, с условием к примеру страница выростит и начнёт кушать ресурсы? "

Comment: Если нужен будет более быстрый язык - Java, C
Чтобы облегчить работу базы данных при большом кол-ве посетителей имеет смысл смотреть в сторону Redis и подобных ему технологий.

Comment: >снова, и снова ответы про меня а не про вопрос

ответом на вопрос является абзац, начинающийся со слова "следовательно"

про страницу, которая "выростит и начнёт кушать ресурсы?" - это довольно..хм..спорное утверждение. Тем не менее, если вас все же беспокоит вопрос тысяч и миллионов, то грамотное использование PHP и MySql позволяет решить эту задачу без проблем. Иллюстрацией могут служить уже набившие оскомину примеры про Фэйсбук, Контакт и Википедию, написанные на PHP

Comment: Ява выглядит давольно интересно и перспективно.

Фэйсбук, Контакт написан на полностью переделонном PHP, а написать свой язык - я точно "сыроват" )

Redis - очень быстр и т.д. но у него цели другие.

Comment: >Фэйсбук, Контакт написан на полностью переделонном PHP

про полностью переделанный php в Контакте кто вам сказал? Дуров всего около месяца назад что-то там говорил про kPHP. И потом, отбросьте свою манию величия - вам не нужно равняться на Фэйсбук и ВКонтакте. Напишите хотя бы просто работающий сайт.  Или у вас есть сколько-нибудь объективные причины полагать, что внутри обычного php вам негде развернуться?

Comment: P.S.: Все "сомнения" начались после просмотра этой http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/

Comment: Контакт писался великими программистами - победителями мировых олимпиад по программированию!, на момент написания, они скорее всего знали более 5 языков программирования, у них "оптимизация" вырабатывалась годами тренировок ) Фейсбук тоже писался достаточно гениальным человеком )

Comment: ну "великими" это несколько громко сказано) Великих не так уж много на свете